# Trying to login with curl in a forum

Tags: parsing, curl

I'm trying to autenticate in a forum with curl but I cant log in. Is like there is no way to load/save well the cookies. Could you help me please?
Many thanks and sorry for my english!

```
curl --cookie cjar \
    --cookie-jar cjar   \ 
    --data 'dest=/?' \
    --data 'username=yyyyy' \
    --data 'password=xxxxx' \
    --location \
    --output loginResult.html \
    http://www.yoloestoyviendo.com/ucp.php?mode=login


curl --cookie cjar   \
     --output inbox.html \
     http://www.yoloestoyviendo.com/viewforum.php?f=1460
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the cookies:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -e website.com -d 'xx=yy' http://website.com/path/to/resource
```

The `-b(--cookie)` means use the cookie from cookies.txt,
and the `-c(--cokie-jar)` means dumps the cookie to cookies.txt.

Then:

```
curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt http://website.com/some_thing_need_login
```

Comment: Thanks. I try with `curl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt --data 'username=uuuuu' --data 'password=yyyyy' --output loginResult.html http://www.yoloestoyviendo.com/ucp.php?mode=login` but doesnt works. I see in the loginResult.html that I'm not logged in

Comment: That means you haven't login successfuly. Did you capture the packages to determin the data fields you need post?

Comment: @user650034 e.g. You can use firbug or other pacp tools capture package :).

Comment: Thanks. When I capture the capture of the post says: `curl 'http://www.yoloestoyviendo.com/ucp.php?mode=login' -H 'Host: www.yoloestoyviendo.com' -H ..... -H 'Referer: http://www.yoloestoyviendo.com/ucp.php?mode=login' -H 'Cookie: phpbb3_ezsu3_u=1; phpbb3_ezsu3_k=; phpbb3_ezsu3_sid=a06ac523dd1bbb994e1a4caf1a155e7d' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data 'username=uuuuu&password=pppppp&sid=a06ac523dd1bbb994e1a4caf1a155e7d&redirect=index.php&login=Identificarse'`

Comment: So need add the correct post data fileds: "username", "password", "sid", "redirect" and "login".

Comment: In my experence , it usual in the html text or the response text of a ajax request. We can go to chat room . :)

Comment: @user650034 I visite the site you give ,and I found the sid is in the html text, just the login href. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44420/discussion-between-atupal-and-user650034)